# Execute remote script with NRPE

Tags: vbscript, nagios, nrpe

You can execute a script if you specify a plugin command on the remote server.
In the example below the plugin command is `get_disk`:

```
 command[get_disk]=csript.exe c:\nagios\checks\check_disks_percentage_spave_used.vbs
```

I would however like NRPE on the remote server to execute a script on the client server, without a plugin command.
On the remote server something like this:

```
check_nrpe  -H 196.35.132.9 -t 60 -c 'csript.exe c:\\nagios\\checks\\check_disks_percentage_space_used.vbs'
```

Comment: This question is about infrastructure administration, not about a programming topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can follow following steps to run a command from nagios to monitor a remote machine

1. lets just say you have 2 machines,
2. from where you want to monitor ( will call it master)
3. to whom u want to monitor ( will call it slave)
4. assuming you are working in linux and in master machine nagios location is "/usr/local/nagios"
5. your slave machine is also linux and nrpe installation location is "/usr/local/nagios"
6. put your script/plugin/executable file in slave machine @ /usr/local/nagios/libexec location.

   > e.g. - /usr/local/nagios/libexec/test.sh 
   > and give it executable permission. 
   >   
   > chmod +x test.sh

   7. edit nrpe.cfg and add the command there as

   > vi /usr/local/nagios/etc/nrpe.cfg
   >   
   >  add following line 
   >   
   >  command[testScript]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/test.sh 
   >   
   >  ***telling nrpe to run test.sh when it receives testScript command***

8. restart nrpe
9. goto master machine
10. edit commands.cfg

> vi /usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/commands.cfg
>   and add following line
>
> define command{
>   command_name check_nrpe
>   command_line /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -c $ARG1$
>   }
>   ***by adding this, now master machine is aware what is check_nrpe command.***

11. add a service

    > define service{
    >   use generic-service
    >   host_name web-node01
    >   service_description count number of cmd in remote mc
    >   check_command check_nrpe!testScript
    >   }
    >   
    >   ***now nagios know that it has to call testScript command in slave machine,
    >  and in slave machine we have defined when received testScript command run 'test.sh' 
    > from thi s'/usr/local/nagios/libexec' location (point no. 7)***
12. now before trying it from nagios you can directly call the nrpe command to check is everything is working fine by following command

    > /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H slave_IP_Address -c testScript
    >   
    > **P.S. this is exactly same command that nagios will run behind the scene**

Comment: Thanks @GKV, I ended up doing something like that. Had to make the changes on 125 remote (slave) machine

Comment: 11. add a service ... but where? That seems to be commonly left out of descriptions.  I would think /usr/local/nagois/etc/servers/yourServer.cfg but adding the "define service" block causes nagios service to fail to load in that file causes nagios to fail to restart.

Comment: Up voted for the effort put into the answer. It actually really helped me understand how Nagios works :)